# What is the UDC number for uchronia?

Tags: genre, library-and-information-science

What number should [uchronia](http://www.uchronia.net/), ie fiction concerning a 'hypothetical or fictional time period of our world, in contrast to altogether-fictional lands or worlds' ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchronia)), have in the Universal Decimal Classification?

In [literature section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Decimal_Classification#8_Language._Linguistics._Literature) I find:

> 82-94 History as literary genre. Historical writing. Historiography. Chronicles. Annals. Memoirs

But “History as literary genre” is not exactly an uchronia with an alternate universe.

So is there a deeper branch of UDC dedicated to uchronia?

Comment: [Alternate history](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/alternate_history) would be classified under "82-3 Fiction. Prose narrative", since it is fictional.